# Oracle Database Server memory increasing day by day until reach 100%

Tags: oracle

[image]I facing issue on Oracle Database 11gR2 DB ( Oracle Linux 7.7 OS). Our server has 128 GB of Memory, we configured 60% of physical memory for SGA+PGA ( Automatic Memory Management). We have around 2000 clients which running Oracle Form base software. After up and running some days, our server memory keep increasing until reach 100% memory then system hang because of lacking memory for OS. We tried reboot server some times but issue still there. We can not found any thing which eating much memory. Each client session only consume around 10MB of memory.

Could you please guide me how to troubleshoots this issue? It really impact much to company performance.

Big thanks!

Comment: This really sounds like your connection pool might have persistent (but perhaps occasional) leaks.  You should check whatever keeps connecting to your Oracle database, and make sure that all connections are being released properly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, our clients running and keep connection almost all time of day to update devices test logs, confirm material.., only free in meal time and Sunday. At meal time, and Sunday, Memory usage reduce to certain level, but after that, it will increase to higher than before meal time. Number of session stable at 2150. I just update picture so you can imagine.

Comment: Then it's pretty clear what the source of the connection hogging is.  Check your application code for leaks.

Comment: We have a development team located in other country. We are fighting each other because of this. I tried to figure out evidence to show them that issue may come from application but still can't.  I am really new and less experience about this kind of issues. Could you please guide me how to get "connection hogging"? Thanks your quick answer btw!

Comment: I'm not an expert in Oracle DBA matters, but there should be some kind of admin panel from which you can view open connections.  If you can plot numbers of active users against number of open connections, you can try to show that as users come online, you lose connections.

Comment: Do you think inactive session is potential problem?

Comment: If check in OS point of view, each connection will create one process in Linux  ps aux | grep -i oracle | wc -l  
2127

Comment: Any help pls! This is my urgent case. Thanks